# How do I handle/edit large amount of text in WPF?

Tags: wpf, performance, text

What would be a good approach to display and edit large amount of unformatted text (just like notepade does) using WPF? Loading a big string into a TextBox makes the UI unresponsive. The overall performance is not nearly comparable with TextBox Controls of previous Microsoft  UI Frameworks.

What options do I have to solve this problem. I do not want to block the UI thread while the text control loads the text. Also I might need some sort of "virtualization" because it might not be a good idea to load the whole text into the control (I guess that 20MB of text would create a lot of glyphs even if they are not visible). It seems that TextBox doesn't even have an AppenText() Method anymore so I don't even have a way to control asynchronous loading of the text.

Isn't this a common problem? It seems that WPF does not provide anything for this out of the box. Why is this so?

Comment: I played with it for just a bit.  The problem seems to have something to do with calculating the scrolling region.  If you disable the scrollbar, the problem sort of goes away -- unless you hit ctrl+end (and then it has to calculate the bottom or something)

the content template for hte textbox is a scrollviewer.  Maybe the issue has more to do with optimizing the scrollviewer.

Not an answer, but maybe a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AvalonEdit, the text editor in SharpDevelop, was written completely from scratch in WPF and is optimized for large amounts of text. It doesn't support rich text (although it does support syntax highlighting and other cool features such as folding). I think this might fit your bill perfectly.

Here is an article on the editor written by the developer:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx

Comment: I have too cometo the conclusion that writing your own text control is probably the best solution. It's a bit sad, though.

Comment: -1. I've used AvalonEdit with 4MB or larger files with horrible results. Extremely buggy and crashes my app like a mad bomber.

Comment: Just created a new VS WPF C# project, add NuGet AvalonEdit.Sample package, change StartupUri, run and voila!, the AvalonEdit application running fine. Opened a 4MB text file with 8k lines in less a second, while TextBlock took 22 seconds. Definitely could be a replacement for TextBlock.

Comment: Replaced TextBlock with AvalonEdit control in my project (LOB app with quite complex UI) but unfortunately spends also 20 seconds to load the same file than in AvalonEdit.Sample standalone app spends <1 second.

Comment: Replaced TextBlock with AvalonEdit and it worked nicely. I have to figure something out for updating the DocumentModel in a background Thread.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this helps, but have you tried using [FlowDocumentPageViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentpageviewer.aspx) and [FlowDocumentReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader.aspx)?

It also has very good annotations support and looks ideal for loading documents in text format.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the TextBox is a single container element. List controls, such as ListBox virtualize very well because of container recycling. There really isn't anything simple that you can do to speed up the TextBox.

But the TextBox control does have an AppendText() method:

```
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.AppendText("Hello");
```

So yes, you can use this to dynamicly add some text just like you mentioned.

Comment: Cool, I was reading the docs and the inherited members where hidden. Since AppendText() comes from TextBoxBase I didn't see it.

Comment: This works well, and it's fast: I can add 10,000 new rows to a TextBox in about a second. As its all virtualized, the scrolling is very quick.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a textbox with a style that gives the user more room to view the text. There are probably more advanced controls from Telerik and others but if you don't require editing options that should suffice.

Comment: The main problem here is perfomance and usability. I do not want to block the UI thread while the text control loads the text also I might need some sort of "virtualization" because it might not be a good idea to load the whole text into the control (20MB of text would create a lot of glyphs).

Comment: In that case I would go with a third party control. You can remove the extra formating features and keep it simple like Notepad. A third party control should be able to better handle amounts of text you are talking about. You can also load the text on another thread and than bind it to the control after it is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You could always mix and match technologies: you could drop a WinForms TextBox onto a WPF parent. You lose things like styling, opacity, animation, transforms, etc., but if all that matters is editing text, the WinForms TextBox does that just fine.

Comment: This is sad, but probably the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the WPF [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx)?  You'll definitely want to read up on the FlowDocument information if you go this route.

Comment: i am surprised something this basic is not handled out of the box.  It is not intuitive at all how to bind text to a richtextbox.

Answer (score 1):

You could use *FlowDocument*, but this doesn't work out of the box to bind to the *Document* property of a *FlowDocument* in MVVM.

Another solution is using *FlowDocumentScrollViewer* and bind to its *Document* property.

(or you could even use a *FlowDocumentReader* and bind its *Document* property, similar to the *FlowDocumentScrollViewer*. This gives you a different UI.)

The View:

```
 <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Document="{Binding FlowDocument, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The ViewModel:

```
   FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        Run r = new Run();
        r.Text = "large text";
        p.Inlines.Add(r);
        fd.Blocks.Add(p);
        FlowDocument = fd;

 private FlowDocument _FlowDocument;
    public FlowDocument FlowDocument
    {
      get{ return _FlowDocument; }
      set
      {
        _FlowDocument = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(FlowDocument));
      }
    }
```

see also this for extra performance tips: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-text#flowdocument-textblock-and-label-controls

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like this:

Keep the whole string in memory but show only a 'slice' of it in the textbox. Size of the that sliced string would be dynamically calculated depending on the size of textbox, font size etc.

Of course this involves a lot of not trivial code for proper displaying, synchronizing and so on, but it seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

One other option is to use [Scintilla.NET](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET). It has the best performance for large amounts of texts I have seen so far. Loading large files is almost instantaneous. Even though it is a WinForms control, you can embed it into your WPF window with WindowsFormsHost container. There is syntax highlighting and some other features that should be more than enough for displaying unformatted text. From the downsides - since this is a WinForms control, it overlaps other WPF UI elements. Also there may be issues with resizing the control. Unfortunately, I don't see any better option than using a non-WPF control instead of the default TextBox and RichTextBox.