# Best way to show huge text in WPF?

Tags: wpf, controls, textview

I need to show a really huge amount of text data in **WPF** code. First i tried to use [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox) (and of course it was too slow in rendering). Now i'm using [FlowDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument)--and its awesome--but recently i have had another request: text shouldnt be hyphenated. Supposedly it is not (`document.IsHyphenationEnabled = false`) but i still don't see my precious horizontal scroll bar. if i magnify scale text is ... hyphenated.

[image]

```
public string TextToShow
{
    set
    {
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(value);

        FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
        document.IsHyphenationEnabled = false;

        flowReader.Document = document;
        flowReader.IsScrollViewEnabled = true;
        flowReader.ViewingMode = FlowDocumentReaderViewingMode.Scroll;
        flowReader.IsPrintEnabled = true;
        flowReader.IsPageViewEnabled = false;
        flowReader.IsTwoPageViewEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

That's how i create FlowDocument - and here comes part of my WPF control:

```
<FlowDocumentReader Name="flowReader" Margin="2 2 2 2" Grid.Row="0" />
```

Nothing criminal =))

I'd like to know how to tame this beast - googled nothing helpful. Or you have some alternative way to show megabytes of text, or textbox have some virtualization features which i need just to enable. Anyway i'll be happy to hear your response!

Comment: Your problem is not hyphenation. It's wrap around. Take a look here: http://msdn.itags.org/visual-studio/36912/ , they suggest setting the width of the paragraph larger than the view window.

Comment: Thanks Omer - link & suggestion seems to be quite sensible. Will try it soon :)

Comment: see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807347/how-do-i-handle-edit-large-amount-of-text-in-wpf/46546877#46546877

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really wrapping not hyphenation. And one can overcome this by setting FlowDocument.PageWidth to reasonable value, the only question was how to determine this value.
Omer suggested this recipe [msdn.itags.org/visual-studio/36912/](http://msdn.itags.org/visual-studio/36912/) but i dont like using TextBlock as an measuring instrument for text. Much better way:

```
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(value);


            FormattedText text = new FormattedText(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(paragraph.FontFamily, paragraph.FontStyle, paragraph.FontWeight, paragraph.FontStretch), paragraph.FontSize, Brushes.Black );

            FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
            document.PageWidth = text.Width*1.5;
            document.IsHyphenationEnabled = false;
```

Omer - thanks for the direction.